# Probability density function of max(0, z)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

##### Question

The full question is from Exercise 4.6 in Statistical Inference (Casella, Berger). It is

> A and B agree to meet at certain place between 1 PM to 2 PM. Suppose they arrive at meeting place independently and randomly during the hour. Find the distribution of the length of time that A waits for B (If B arrives before A, define A's waiting to be 0)

##### My answer

Here we can assume $A$ and $B$ to be uniform (that is $U(0,1)$) and we are interested to find the PDF of $T = max(0, B-A)$ where

$$
f(a, b) = 1
$$

To solve this, what I did is that first find out the PDF of $C = B - A$ as shown below

Define $D = B + A$, then joint distribution of (C, D) will be
$$
g(c, d) = f\left(\frac{d-c}{2}, \frac{d+c}{2}\right)\left|\begin{vmatrix}\frac{-1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{vmatrix}\right|
$$
that is $g(c,d) = \frac{1}{2}$ where $-1<c<0$ and $-c<d<c+2$, $0<c<1$ and $c<d<2-c$

Now the marginal distribution of $C$ will be
$$
h(c) = 
\begin{cases}
1 + c & \text{if $-1 < c < 0$} \\
1 - c & \text{if $0 < c < 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

Now our required variable $T$ will be $T = \max(0, C)$ and this is where I am stuck that is how to find out the distribution of $T$.

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Your question is quite vague as it is, what exactly is it that you are curious of?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have update the question with more details.

Comment: The difference between two uniform variables is not uniform.

Comment: (Between two _independent_ uniform variables, I mean.)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Huge mistake from my side when calculating the bounds for c and d and the joint distribution. Have corrected the calculation and also the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To solve this, what I did is that first find out the PDF of C=B−A as shown below

Indeed, or you could do $$\begin{align}f_{A,B-A}(a,c) &=\begin{vmatrix}\partial a/\partial a&\partial a/\partial c\\\partial (a+c)/\partial a&\partial(a+c)/\partial c\end{vmatrix} f_{A,B}(a, a+c)\\f_{B-A}(c) &=\int_\Bbb R f_A(a)f_B(a+c)\,\mathrm d a\\[1ex]&=\int_\Bbb R \mathbf 1_{0<a<1, 0<a+c<1}\,\mathrm d a\\[1ex]&= \int_{-c}^1 \mathbf 1_{-1\leqslant c<0}\,\mathrm d a+\int_0^{1-c}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant c\leqslant 1}\,\mathrm d a\\[1ex]&=(1+c)\,\mathbf 1_{-1\leqslant c<0}+(1-c)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant c\leqslant 1} \end{align}$$

---

> Now our required variable $T$ will be $T=max(0,C)$ and this is where I am stuck that is how to find out the distribution of $T$.

The issue is that $T=0$ is the event $C\leq 0$, which will *not* have a *probability density*.  Rather it will have a *probability mass* of $1/2$ .

You might use the Dirac Delta generalised function for this.

$$f_T(t) = \tfrac 12\delta(t)+(1-t)\,\mathbf 1_{0<t\leqslant 1}$$